# JMeter - save assertion results as a variable

Tags: automation, jmeter, assertions

In JMeter I have an automation test plan with several assertions. In my assertion result listener I can see the result off all assertions in a handy overview. So far so good.

At the end of the test plan, I'm calling JIRA to post a new issue with the test results. I want the description of that issue to contain the overview from the assertion result listener.

How can I define the assertion results as a variable, so that I can reference them later in my JIRA call?

[How can I map this view to a variable?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylV2M.png)

My JIRA call should look like this:

POST /rest/api/2/issue

```
{
"fields": {
   "project":
   {
      "key": "Blah"
   },
   "assignee": {
      "name": "Joe"
    },
    "priority": {
      "name": "Major"
    },
   "summary": "Jmeter Test Result",
   "description": "${assertionresults}",
   "issuetype": {
      "name": "Test Execution"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add after the Sampler with the assertion:

[Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) and inside it a [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and write the following code using [AssertionResult.getFailureMessage](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/AssertionResult.html#getFailureMessage--) method:

```
  vars.put("assertionresults", prev.getAssertionResults()[0].getFailureMessage());
```

It will save in `assertionresults` variable the first assertion message.

Comment: Can I do the same for the other assertions in my test plan, like so:

`vars.put("assertionresults2", prev.getAssertionResults()[0].getFailureMessage());`

And then in the JIRA call reference them accordingly?