# Jmeter action based on assertion result

Tags: jmeter, slack

I am using a HTTP request with duration assertion of 1 second. I want an alerting system slack/mail whenever my assertion fails. Is it possible to do so using Jmeter ? if yes how ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) after the request which may be not successful
2. Use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false,)}
   ```

   [image]

   `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` is a [pre-defined JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) which holds the result of previous [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) execution so If Controllers child/children will be only executed if the previous request is not successful.
3. Put the logic which sends email or slack notification as a child of the If Controller
4. That's it, the notification will be sent only if the sampler is not successful

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You save the assertion result to a var. see: [JMeter - save assertion results as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286630/jmeter-save-assertion-results-as-a-variable)
2. Use if controller to decide weather to send slack / mail.

Comment: can you please share the step by step logic for the same as the other answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Have a look at @Dmitri's response above, it seems to explain it very well.